# Reusing external image in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I have an imported external buffer, which starts out with PREINITIALIZED layout, which is then switched to TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL with a memory barrier before copying the data out.

That works well once, but now I'd like to reuse the image in the next frame, i.e. after the image copy is complete, I'd have the external hardware fill new data into memory, and make sure that the next frame uses the new data.

Is an image barrier without a layout change the correct approach here, as I'm not allowed to take the layout back to PREINITIALIZED?

Comment: Layout depends on what specifically you do with the image. `GENERAL` is the equivalent of `PREINITIALIZED`.

Comment: @krOoze The image is used as a texture, but I make an extra transfer to go from the format the FPGA generates to what the GPU prefers for textures -- so my expectation would be that TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL is correct here -- I'm unsure about the barrier operation though, does it do anything if there is technically "no change"?

Comment: That means nothing to me. Vulkan layouts are specifically tied to access commands. So which access command do you use to update the data?

Comment: @krOoze, the memory backing for the buffer is [external](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_external_memory_fd.html), and is updated by external hardware. So from the point of view of the GPU, the data changes without a command. I could add an external [semaphore](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_external_semaphore_fd.html) or [fence](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_KHR_external_fence_fd.html) if that helps.

Comment: It cannot be updated by external hardware. Pretty sure that is prohibited. You can only import memory of the same hardware (but different API or process). IIRC you must match the device through UUID before importing.